# What's the practical difference between an interface, a type, and an abstract class in OOP languages like Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, data-structures, types

What's the practical difference between an interface, a type, and an abstract class in OOP languages like Python?

Links to Wikipedia:

[Interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface-based_programming), [type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_type) and [abstract class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_type).

Comment: Python doesn't actually use these terms (with the exception of the ``type`` class – something else than the *concept* of "a type"), and the articles you link to don't map 1:1 to Python either. What exactly are you asking about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python has [duck typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing) :

> If it walks like a duck and it quacks like a duck, then it must be a duck

Which means that this works :

```
class Duck:
    def quack(self):
        print("quack!")


class Car:
    def quack(self):
        print("vroum!")  # for example purposes


def make_it_quack(something):
    something.quack()  # don't care what it is, just that it quacks


make_it_quack(Duck())  # quack!
make_it_quack(Car())  # vroum!
```

Python at runtime will try to call the `quack` method on your object, and fails if it does not exist. But as long as the method exist (and the signature fit), Python does not care of the actual type of the object.

In other languages, you would have needed to define a base class (possibly **abstract**) that both child classes would have to inherit. And if there are multiple different sets of methods you want your object to have, either you *1)* can do multiple-inheritance, *2)* you build tall hierarchies of (abstract) base classes, or *3)* you create lots of interfaces. Python does not **need** any of this, but it does not provide you static guarantees that your code type checks either.

If you want, there exist some ways to have more type checks in Python :

- you can declare abstract base classes using the standard library [`abc`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html)
- you can add type annotations to your code and use an external type checker (for exemple [MyPy](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/getting_started.html)).

**TL;DR** : Python is duck-typed, but there is tooling if you want the guarantees that come with interface contracts.

Comment: thank you for the answaer and compreenssion

Answer (score -1):

Reading the book [design patterns GoF](https://www.amazon.com.br/Design-Patterns-Elements-Reusable-Object-Oriented/dp/0201633612/ref=asc_df_0201633612/?tag=googleshopp00-20&linkCode=df0&hvadid=379735814613&hvpos=&hvnetw=g&hvrand=18311992972574853079&hvpone=&hvptwo=&hvqmt=&hvdev=c&hvdvcmdl=&hvlocint=&hvlocphy=1001686&hvtargid=pla-395340045790&psc=1) they explain that interface is the shell with methods publicy available, the type is the inner structure of data and the abstract class could be the form that the data will be based when the script build an object, that looks like a type.